# How to move subquery to WITH statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM app_interfaces
WHERE ROWID IN (
    SELECT MAX (ROWID)
    FROM app_interfaces
    WHERE version <= (SELECT MAX (version) AS v FROM app_interfaces)
    GROUP BY id);
```

I'm not sure if this is the "proper" way to write this query, and I'm trying to use Oracle's WITH clause like so:

```
WITH latest_version AS (
SELECT MAX(version) AS v FROM app_interfaces )
SELECT *
FROM app_interfaces
WHERE ROWID IN (  
    SELECT MAX (ROWID)
    FROM app_interfaces
    WHERE version <= latest_version.v
    GROUP BY id);
```

Can you tell me A) which technique is more efficient? B) Why the second technique (with with) is incorrect?

[Edit]

The intent of this query is the following:

I have a model where each entry is associated with a 'version' (so one entity in the app_interfaces model may have multiple versions). However, these versions are determined based on a date, so they're not necessarily sequential (I could have 1402, 1403, 1407, etc.).

If I'm looking at version X of my model, I want to see all entries at version X or the next latest version of the entities which don't have that version number.

So if app A has entries for versions 1402, 1403, and 1407; and app B has entries for versions 1402 and 1405, and I query for the latest version (1407), I would expect to get teh 1407 entry for app A and the 1405 entry for app B. Ideally I'd have another query I could use to specify particular entries (instead of the max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't.  You need to mention the CTE in a `from` clause:

```
WITH latest_version AS (
      SELECT MAX(version) AS v FROM app_interfaces
     )
SELECT *
FROM app_interfaces
WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT MAX(ROWID)
                FROM app_interfaces
                WHERE version <= (SELECT v FROM latest_version)
                GROUP BY id
               );
```

Unless `version` can be `NULL`, the comparison doesn't do anything.  So, your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM app_interfaces
WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT MAX(ROWID)
                FROM app_interfaces
                GROUP BY id
               );
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM app_interfaces
WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT MAX(ROWID)
                FROM app_interfaces
                WHERE version IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY id
               );
```

Comment: That's really interesting- I wouldn't have expected it to work that way (but then again, I'm not really a SQL guy). The comparison originally came from a version of the query where I wanted to specify the 'max' (more details in the edited question).